# PayPal Sandbox links go to live PayPal site

Tags: paypal, hyperlink, sandbox

I can log into the developer.paypal.com site with my PayPal credentials. When I then enter the sandbox as my seller account, all of the links in the menu system takes me to the live PayPal site, instead of the sandbox. I have been able to hack the url and prepend "sandbox." and in some cases that gets me into the IPN history and Recurring Payment Profiles. I can live with that work around if I need to.

My main issue right now is that I can't access any transaction history for my seller account. It goes to the transaction history on the live PayPal site, and shows me the transaction history for the PayPal account that I initially used to log into the developer site.

This is really holding up my project.

Any one have any insights?

I've tried things like deleting cookies, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is (unfortunately) common for the sandbox to be broken in the ways you describe.  However, this should not be holding up your project -- the sandbox is mainly useful for checkout/API testing, and there is very little need to review transaction history in the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same very annoying problem. I need to list the transactions because sometimes I want to delete them (they are recurring payments) so I am in control of which IPNs actually go to my test website.

After playing around with the sandbox, I have found that at first, the "history" link will send you directly to the live paypal site but if you first select "Withdraw", then the nav menu will display the correct "history" link (i.e. https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/fr/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=%5fhistory&nav=0%2e3)

The screen will give you access to the 20 latest transactions; I haven't found yet how one moves to the next page without being sent to the live Paypal site.

If I delete the seller test account, will it cancel all the existing future recurring payments?

Cheers.